# Clean Architecture: should i have a use case for each Http End point?

Tags: web-applications, use-case, clean-architecture

Suppose i must create a web page where user:

- Search products
- Click on specific product and show details
- Change some details and click Save.

I excpect my web app will have a ProductController with three actions: one for list, one for detail, one for save changes.

Should i have three distinct user cases (then three classes) or is sufficient to have a single class (e.g. ProductInteractor) with three methods ?

I'm afraid that having a use case for each entry point would generate a lot of boiler code..

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have already designed three controller actions, what difference would it make if you design three interactors?

After all, you do have three different use cases, so my advice to you is to follow SRP (single responsibility principle) and let each use case have its own interactor.

That would give you more flexibility in a sense that it would be easy, for example, to replace an existing implementation of products search with a new one - independently from the other interactors.